# Multiple \maketitle and Headers

Tags: header-footer, titling, titleps

I'm using the `titling` package to allow me to have multiple `\maketitle` tags in a document.

I also want to have headers telling me which "section" (as given by the title) I am in.

However, the header changes before the chapter changes, see page 2 of the minimal example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% header
\makeatletter
\newpagestyle{main}{
\sethead[\@title][][] % even
{}{}{\textsl{\@title} % odd
\setfoot[\thepage][][] % even
{}{}{\thepage} % odd
}}
\pagestyle{main}

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{\flushleft\LARGE\bfseries \@title \par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{First Title}
\maketitle

\lipsum


\title{Second Title}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Comment: My advice is to use a standard sectioning command such as `\section`

Comment: If you want chapters, why are you using `article`? Plus why load `titling` but then redefine the low level command `\@maketitle`?

Comment: To answer the first comment: This is a minimal example. In reality, we are writing many stand-alone worksheets that are then dropped into a master document. It is important that the stand-alone worksheets have "standard" latex syntax with `\maketitle` etc. Then using `\input`, and turning off `\documentclass` etc, we can get ourselves into a situation like the one above. So using `\section` doesn't help

Comment: To answer the second comment: This may only be due to my ignorance. I needed to completely redo how tiles/abstracts are displayed. In fact, looking at the titling package, I am not sure it had the flexibility I needed. Again, this is a minimal working example, it shows the pathology I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Ah! The fix is as simple as adding a `\clearpage` before the `\title{Second Title}`